# Joomla External HTML and Access Levels

Tags: html, plugins, joomla, external, joomla1.5

I am trying to use Joomla to create a website that allows users to do the following:

- submit links to external html
- search through the external websites based on category, rankings, etc.
- display the websites in multiple iframes simultaneously ( like google gadgets)
- limit access to certain external websites by user
- customize users homepage (like igoogle)

I am trying to pull the right joomla plugin and component pieces together.

For i-frame display I am looking at:

http://www.joomlaclub.gr/joomla-free-downloads.html?func=fileinfo&id=46
http://www.cmsmarket.com/extensions-directory/external+content/frames+%26+external+html/praiseframe+module
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-&-design/popups-&-iframes/3116/details

Can you think of any extensions, plugins, or components that would help me build the aforementioned functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, Joomla allows users to submit a link after they register / login.

Make sure the 'login module' is published.  Then in the Menu Manager, User Menu, make sure the menu items for submitting links are there.

I'm not really sure what you mean by 'search through the external websites based on category, rankings, etc.'

Displaying the web sites in multiple iframes simultaneously could easily be handled by publishing modules which contain iframes in the postion you desire.

In Joomla 1.6, still in beta, there is a fairly robust ACL.  But in 1.5, you'd need to use some extension.  I've had good luck with the ACL component CorePHP sells.

Good luck with your project  !